# Absolute positioning in FF

Tags: css, firefox, positioning, absolute

I´ve got a problem with position:absolute in FF. I´ve got a bar with a width of 100% and two bars with a static width on the left and right side. 
I need to do set the inner Bar to 100% to make it responsive. It looks bad when I give percentage-values to the borders. 
In Chrome and even IE!!! it´s working fine but Firefox adds both short bars to the right side (like on the picture).

```
HTML:
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span12">
            <div id="slider">
                <button class="scrllbtn">〈</button>
                <div id="sliderFrame">
                    <div id="innerSlider">
                        <button class="videoButton">▶</button>
                        <button class="videoButton">▶</button>
                        <button class="videoButton">▶</button>
                        <button class="videoButton">▶</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button class="scrllbtn">〉</button>
            </div>
            <div id="videos"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>

Styles:

    #wrapper
    {
        width: 960px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        border: solid 1px red;
    }

    #slider {
        padding-top: 0.4em;
        clear:left;
        width:100%;
        height: 160px;
        display:block;
    }
    #sliderFrame {
        width:100%;
        height:160px;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        overflow-y:hidden;
        float:left;
        border-top: solid 1px #043860;
        border-bottom: solid 1px #043860;
    }
    #innerSlider {
        width:950px;
        height:200px;
        clear:none;
    }
    .scrllbtn {
        position: absolute;
        height:162px;
        width: 20px;
    }
    .scrllbtn:first-child {
        clear:left !important;
    }
    .scrllbtn:last-child {
        margin-left: -20px;
        float:right;
    }
    .scrllbtn:focus {
        outline: none;
    }
    .videoButton {
        float:left;
        width:200px;
        height:160px;
    }
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bmdjL/4/)

Any suggestetions how I could solve that problem?

[image: Expected]

Comment: it was not allowed to post a picture... I hope my problem is understandable

Comment: Put link to picture on imgur or other hosting

Comment: How about setting up the centre box with a width of 100% and then adding margin: 0 20px; thus creating the 'space for the side bars ?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/LQOjyeY.png?1" title="Hosted by imgur.com

Comment: Have you delclared `left` or `right` along with `position:absolute;` ??

Comment: @Pat Dobson: This is what i did, but i causes problems in ff

Comment: @Nathan Lee: All is wrapped in the middle and left and right is not relative to the wrapper. So it appears outside of it.

Comment: Please post your markup and css.

Comment: Sorry! it´s my first post on Stackoverflow. Now everything should be fine.

Comment: This is how it finally works using bootstrap. (It´s the first time that bootstrap is helping)
Please, note that it´s not working without using Bootstrap!

http://jsfiddle.net/bmdjL/5/

Answer (score 0):

somthing like this `:)`

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rnewD/)

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
</div>

.main {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    background: red;
}

.right {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: orange;
    width: 100px;
    height: 500px;
}


.left {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: gray;
    width: 100px;
    height: 500px;
}
```

Comment: That is not working in my case. It´s positioning the .left and .right in the upper-right corner of my screen. Even with the position absolute in the .main.

Comment: i fix your example see in top :)

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following rule makes it work in my copy of Firefox:

```
.scrllbtn:first-child {
    left: 0;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bmdjL/1/)

Comment: The problem is that it´s wrapped and centere. Now it looks like this: 
http://i.imgur.com/99uXcZ7.png?1

Comment: That's not the same code you posted... Please do a full fiddle yourself.

Answer (score 0):

fix problem in your example `:)`

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bmdjL/3/)

```
<button class="scrllbtn scrllbtnleft">〈</button>
<button class="scrllbtn scrllbtnright">〉</button>

.scrllbtnleft {
    left: 0;
}
.scrllbtnright {
    right: 0;
}
```